sublattices of index 3 contained in a lattice $L $ in $\mathbb{R}^2$
How many sublattices of index 3 are contained in a lattice $L $ in $\mathbb{R}^2 $?
This is a problem in the book Algebra by Michael Artin.
I guess there are only two， but have no clue to find a proof.
A sublattice of index 3 can be generated by an integral matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}$$
whose determinant is 3. The problem is that many matrices generate the same lattice.

Hint: Every sublattice of $\mathbb Z^2$ of index $3$ contains the lattice $(3\mathbb Z)^2$.

See my answer to a more general question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368026/number-of-sublattices-of-bbb-z2/2694288#2694288
